# Will Wizz Air charge extra for a stroller with a car seat clicked in?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, children, wizz-air

We are flying with Wizz Air from London to Warsaw tonight with our newborn. We were planning to take a stroller with a car seat clicked in, so effectively two items. The [Wizz Air website](http://wizzair.com/en-GB/useful_information/faq#2) is quite vague about the details, and the wording of their policy seems to have changed since I did a similar thing with the older children a few years ago.

How likely is it that we will be charged extra and what would be the charge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with this airline, but the link you provided reads:

> Is an infant entitled to any baggage allowance?
>
> Infants are not entitled to any baggage allowance with the exception of a pushchair / foldable baby carriage / infant car seat per infant (carried free of charge).

Ok, infants can bring a stroller and/or carseat for free. I see this sentence as a little ambiguous as to whether you can have both or just one free of charge.

> One of these items will also be carried free of charge for children (between the age  of 2 years and 14 years old).

This sounds like for 2-14 year olds, you can have EITHER a stroller or a carseat. This would lead me to believe you can have both for a baby.

> Please note that prams and pushchairs shall be checked in with other baggage and will be carried free of charge only if the user of the equipment is travelling. However if no infant or child is involved, these items will be carried as checked-in baggage for an additional fee.

This looks like the stroller at least would need to be checked in regularly, and not gate-checked (though this might depend on the airport too).  The kid needs to be travelling with you for the items to be free.
It looks like that IF you have a seat for the infant, you can use the (air plane approved) car seat in the seat. I would expect it to go in the cargo hold otherwise.

In my experience with other airlines (Delta, Lufthansa, Virgin America, United, KLM, Alaskan) I have never had to pay for a stroller or car seat. We usually check the car seat(s) in the luggage, and gate check the stroller. Next long flight coming up we will use the car seat on the plane, since we got a ticket for our youngest too.

Answer (score 4):

I've travelled with WizzAir a few times, I've noticed that the strollers are always put into the Cargo Hold, never seen one in the passenger area. As for the car seat, I would assume that  unless you have a separate seat booked for the new born then that will also have to go in the cargo hold. You are only allowed 1 small cabin bag or 1 large cabin bag (the sizes for these can be found on the WizzAir site). You are able to upgrade your bag sizes at check-in, however the cost of this is about £40. You will be charged to place the stroller and car seat to the cargo hold, I'm unsure of this cost but I would presume that it's dependant on the weight of all your items.

To simplify, stroller and carseat to the cargo hold.

Answer (score 2):

For Wizzair, if you have purchased a separate ticket for your infant, then only car seat is allowed for free of charge otherwise its not. And if ur tickets price is less then 27£ one way, they charge you the same price for your infant even for carrying him on lap. So although you feel you have paid for the infant seat, you have not. You have paid those charges for carrying him on lap. and if that is the case , you cannot carry a car seat for free. 
As far as stroller is concerned, you can carry it for free and drop it at the gate before boarding the aircraft.

Comment: What is your source? Wizzair site? Personal experience?